# Not showing measures in results when using Weatherbit API

Tags: python, api, weather-api

Using Python, need to display the current weather data using the website API https://www.weatherbit.io/api. Weather data should be displayed in text form. I got something like this, but it's not working as expected, as a result it shows following without measures:

```
#Output

 Enter city name : Paris
 Temperature (in kelvin unit) = ['temp']
 atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = ['pres']
 humidity (in percentage) = ['rh']
 description = ['description']
```

Full code:

```
# import required modules
import requests, json

# Enter your API key here
api_key = "API_key"

# base_url variable to store url
base_url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?"
# Give city name
city_name = input("Enter city name : ")

# complete_url variable to store
# complete url address
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name

# get method of requests module
# return response object
response = requests.get(complete_url)

# json method of response object
# convert json format data into
# python format data
x = response.json()


# store the value corresponding
# to the "temp" key of y
current_temperature = ["temp"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "pressure" key of y
current_pressure = ["pres"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "humidity" key of y
current_humidity = ["rh"]

# store the value of "weather"
# key in variable z
z = ["weather"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "description" key at
# the 0th index of z
weather_description = ["description"]

# print following values
print(" Temperature (in kelvin unit) = " +
      str(current_temperature) +
      "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = " +
      str(current_pressure) +
      "\n humidity (in percentage) = " +
      str(current_humidity) +
      "\n description = " +
      str(weather_description))
```

Comment: you forgot `x` in all lines - it has to be `x["temp"]` but you have only `["temp"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `x` in all lines.

To make it more readable I will use name `data` instead of miningless `x`.

```
data = response.json()

current_temperature = data["temp"]
current_pressure    = data["pres"]
current_humidity    = data["rh"]
z                   = data["weather"]
weather_description = data["description"]
```

---

**BTW:**

You could use name `weather` instead of `z` to make code more readable.

See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Full code with other changes (but I don't have `API_KEY` to test it).

- you don't need `import json`
- you could read `API_KEY` from environment (or from `dot file`) for security
- you don't have to create full URL but you can use `get(..., params=...)` for this
- you could use `f-string` to make code more readable
- code is more readable if you use `print()` for every line separatelly.

```
import requests

#import os
#api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")

api_key = "API_KEY"

city_name = input("Enter city name : ")

url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current" # url without `?`

payload = {
    'appid': api_key,
    'q': city_name,
}   

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

data = response.json()

if 'error' in data:
    print('Error:', data['error'])
else:
    temperature = data["temp"]
    pressure    = data["pres"]
    humidity    = data["rh"]
    weather     = data["weather"]
    description = data["description"]

    print(f"Temperature (in kelvin unit) = {temperature}")
    print(f"atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = {pressure}")
    print(f"humidity (in percentage) = {humidity}")
    print(f"description = {description}")
```

---

**EDIT:**

I checked API documentation for [current weather](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/weather-current) and it uses different names in URL.

It has to be

```
payload = {
    'key': api_key,
    'city': city_name,
    #'lang': 'pl'  # for descriptions in my native language Polish
}
```

And it gives `temperature` in `data["data"][0]["temp"]`, `pressure` in `data["data"][0]["pres"]`, etc. - so it needs

```
temperature = data["data"][0]["temp"]
pressure    = data["data"][0]["pres"]
# etc.
```

or you can do

```
data = data['data'][0]

temperature = data["temp"]
pressure    = data["pres"]
```

It also gives `description` in `data["data"][0]["weather"]["description"]`

In other requests it may have more results then `[0]` so you may need to use `for`-loop

```
data = data['data']

for item in data:
    temperature = item["temp"]
    pressure    = item["pres"]
    print(f"Temperature (in kelvin unit) = {temperature}")
    print(f"atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = {pressure}")
```

---

```
import requests

#import os
#api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")

api_key = "ef.............................."

#city_name = input("Enter city name : ")

city_name = 'Warsaw'
url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current" # url without `?`

payload = {
    'key': api_key,
    'city': city_name,
    #'lang': 'pl'  # for descriptions in my native language Polish
}   

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

data = response.json()

if 'error' in data:
    print('Error:', data['error'])
else:
    #print(data)
    
    data = data['data'][0]
    
    temperature = data["temp"]
    pressure    = data["pres"]
    humidity    = data["rh"]
    weather     = data["weather"]
    description = data["weather"]["description"]
    
    print(f"Temperature (in kelvin unit) = {temperature}")
    print(f"atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = {pressure}")
    print(f"humidity (in percentage) = {humidity}")
    print(f"description = {description}")
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation. One thing I tried the improved way that you suggest but the there is error appearing `Error: API key is required.` But I input api key

Comment: I checked documetation for [Current weather](https://www.weatherbit.io/api/weather-current) and it needs `key=` instead of `appid=` and `city=` instead of `q=`. When I run it with my API then it gets data but in different format - it needs to get `data["data"][0]["temp"]` to get temperature - and similar to other values - so I seems your code is totally wrong.

Comment: I added code with all changes and it works for me.

Comment: thank you very much for thorough explanation and for your big help, now I also check and it works perfectly!